# App::build in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Firstly, I'm very new in cakephp. In version 2.x, it allowed App::build to specify Controllers in specified folder. For example:

```
App::build(array(
  'Controller' => array(
    ROOT . '/app/Controller/Api/'
  )
));
```

But in cakephp3.x, App::build is no more available. So how can I make a same thing in cakephp3.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the cakephp doc here : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#configuration, the `App::build` is not a part of cakephp3 anymore.

So, you'll have to make a specific configuration for the cakephp autoloader (use composer):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Controller\\": "/path/to/directory/with/controller/folders"
    }
}
```

More information about this config : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#additional-class-paths

More information about composers autoloader : 
https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: This is a very cumbersome solution, especially because Cake3 offers exactly what he wants by prefix routing.

Comment: @burzum It is, however, the correct answer for the question as it stands.

Comment: @ndm and still not the best way to do it for multiple reasons. Adding it to the autoloader will add it to the search folders, it will look first in the controller folder and then in the added sub-folder. Also the above example is wrong, he should have pasted the 2nd one from the book which shows how to load namespaces from multiple folders. The example above will point *all* controller classes, not just the API ones, to the given folder. My answer will load the right controller immediately because the dispatcher will get the class from the right place directly.

Comment: @burzum Sure, the wrong example side however, the question doesn't say anything about prefixes being used, maybe that is what the OP is actually doing, who knows, in that case prefix routing would of course be the way to go, but for now the question is only about an `App::build()` equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

`App::build` has been removed but what you want can be done with [prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) in Cake3. This is exactly what you try to solve. Taken from the documentation:

> Prefixes are mapped to sub-namespaces in your application’s Controller namespace. By having prefixes as separate controllers you can create smaller and simpler controllers. Behavior that is common to the prefixed and non-prefixed controllers can be encapsulated using inheritance, Components, or traits. Using our users example, accessing the URL `/admin/users/edit/5` would call the `edit()` method of our `src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php` passing 5 as the first parameter. The view file used would be `src/Template/Admin/Users/edit.ctp`

Just replace `admin` with `api` from the example and read *the whole* section of the manual I've linked and you're done.